# Is there any way to add mobile environment as development to ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, bundle, minify

I would like to add environment for mobile in ASP.NET Core. I mean to add isMobile condition to include more js file

```
<environment include="Development" ismobile="true">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

Comment: The environment defines the environment the application runs on, not the client

Comment: To develop for mobile use Xamarin with API on server.